# Add hyperlink to Apple Passbook front page

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet, passkit

I tried to find solution for this across lot of resources on the internet including the Passbook documentation but I didn't have any success.

I know it's possible to add hyperlink on the back of the Passbook but that's not something I can use.

I'm trying to create a Passbook with the logo, date and title on the top, two hyperlinks (buttons) in the middle and the barcode in the bottom of the Passbook.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to add hyperlinks to the fields on the front of a pass. The data detector behaviour of Wallet only applies to back fields.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/FieldDictionary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH4-SW5

Under the Standard Field section, you'll see mention of dataDetectorTypes. It's stated there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! If that's not possible, do you know if I can somehow create my own button which will open the back side or at least if I can somehow customize the icon of the existing "i" button. I need somehow to force users to click on the hyperlinks.. but I'm afraid there is no standard way to do this :)

Comment: That's something I looked at a few years back for a startup I was involved with. Unfortunately, there just isn't a solution. We changed the description of the barcode to read "tap the I for more info", but people didn't really see it. The closes we came was using the Associated App so users would launch the app, but it didn't solve our problem. Would you mind marking my answer as accepted?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm happy that I'm not the only one who want this to be possible in the future versions of the Apple Passbook. It's really nice piece of software and it would be good to make it more customizable.